# Wall putty and moisture accumulation

Tags: moisture, patching-drywall

I recently patched a few anchor holes in the wall that were about 9mm in diameter with wall putty.

It seems natural that some of the moisture goes into the wall interior when it dries. Could something like increase the humidity inside the wall space or would it likely be negligible?

Comment: That's an absurdly minor amount of moisture. Think nothing of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll make its way out eventually as well.

Moisture will migrate through drywall until equilibrium is reached. The short term wetness of mud/wall putty is of no issue.